# Database query select customer info

Tags: mysql, database, heidisql

I have a question, I trying to retrieve a user's data from the database with the following information:

They thing that i need is the, Firstname, Lastname and Email of the customer who purchased the product with reference 1800 and 1898. 
before 2018-05-18.

I have tried this query:

```
select
ps_customer.firstname, lastname , email
from
ps_customer
inner join
ps_product
where
ps_product.reference in (1800,1898) and ps_product.date_add >= 2018-05-18
```

but that gives just all the information of **ALL** customers back and that's not what i want.

Comment: If you said, before 2018-05-18. your where statement should be ps_product.date_add < 2018-05-18 no? and your joining should be unique key rather than your where clause

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all values are from the first table ps_customer you must specify which table they are in with table.column for all values, while you have adressed only the first value.

You should give the table an alias with the AS for better readability, example below.

You will also have to specify on which attribute the columns are joining, in an ON statement. The value has to be the same for both tables.

```
select cus.firstname, cus.lastname , cus.email 
from ps_customer AS cus
inner join ps_product AS prod
ON cus.uniqueKey = prod.uniqueKey
where prod.reference in (1800,1898) and prod.date_add >= 2018-05-18;
```

EDIT:
With the additions of the pictures, I assume you have a sale table that refers to a customer and a product. I believe the best way to structure this query is to:

```
SELECT customer.firstname, customer.lastname, customer.email
FROM ps_product_sale AS sale               (if this is the table with sales records)
INNER JOIN ps_product AS product
      ON sale.id_product = product.id_product
INNER JOIN ps_customer AS customer
      ON customer.id_customer = sale.id_customer
WHERE product.reference in (1800,1898) 
      AND product.date_add >= 2018-05-18;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather join the ps_product table onto the ps_customer table using a unique key that both of the tables have in common (whether it be a customer ID or product ID, depends on the columns you have available in both tables), and then put my limitations in a separate where clause. Also put the date in your where clause in **single quotations**:

eg.

```
select ps_customer.firstname, lastname , email
from ps_customer c
inner join ps_product p on c.customerid = p.customerid
where ps_product.reference in (1800,1898) and ps_product.date_add >= '2018-05-18';
```